# How to convert tree of classes to tree of structs in Swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, tree

I have the following two types

```
class Node {
    var title: String
    var children: [Node]?
}

struct Section {
    let title: String
    let subsections: [Section]
}
```

I have a tree of nodes with multiple roots. That is, an array of `[Nodes]`.
I want to convert this tree to another one of type `[Section]`
How I can do this?

Comment: you'd need to traverse the tree and convert

Answer (score 0):

If there is an array of `[Node]` then you can convert to array of struct as follows:

```
func getTreeOfSections(nodes: [Node]) -> [Section] {
    
    var sections = [Section]()
    for node in nodes {
        let section = getSection(from: node)
        sections.append(section)
    }
    return sections
}

func getSection(from node: Node) -> Section {
    let title = node.title
    var subsections = [Section]()
    for child in node.children {
        let subsection = getSection(from: child)
        subsections.append(subsection)
    }
    return Section(title: title, subsections: subsections)
}
```